# Update parent's state through callback prop from children (React.js)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a **Page.jsx** using a **Form.jsx** component:

```
<Form isValid={this.enableButton} isInvalid={this.disableButton}>
  <Input validation={{ presence: true }} />
</Form>
```

The point is: `Form` needs to check each `Input` validness to proceed. To achieve this, I am doing this in `Form.jsx`:

```
// ...
allInputsAreValid: function () {
  return _.all(this.state.inputsValidation, function (inputsValidation) {
    return inputsValidation.error === false;
  });
}
// ...
```

Then, in `render` method of `Form.jsx`:

```
if (this.allInputsAreValid()) {
  this.props.isValid();
} else {
  this.props.isInvalid();
}
```

Finally, the methods `enable`/`disableButton` (on **Form.jsx**):

```
// ...
enableButton: function () {
  this.setState({
    canSubmit: true
  });
},

disableButton: function () {
  this.setState({
    canSubmit: false
  });
}
//...
```

Changing the state in these methods, the console throws an error:

> Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: setState(...): Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render`). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state.

Why? How to fix?

Comment: `<Form />` is consuming `enableButton` / `disableButton` from the `Page.jsx`. When the form is valid—checked through `allInputsAreValid` method—, then one of these methods are invoked. The point is: changing the state from there results in that error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to move this logic out of the `render` method:

```
if (this.allInputsAreValid()) {
  this.props.isValid();
} else {
  this.props.isInvalid();
}
```

**Update:**

Let's modify your `<Input />` components to accept an `onChange` prop. I'm not sure if you are using ES6 classes or `React.createClass`, but I will go the ES6 classes route here.

```
class Input extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <input type="text" onChange={this.props.onChange} />;
  }
}
```

Then modify your **Form.jsx** to give the inputs an `onChange` property.

```
<Form isValid={this.enableButton} isInvalid={this.disableButton}>
  <Input
    validation={{ presence: true }}
    onChange={() => {
      if (this.allInputsAreValid()) {
        this.props.isValid();
      } else {
        this.props.isInvalid();
      }
    }}
  />
</Form>
```

Comment: `componentDidMount` only occurs once. I need to check in every state changing.

Comment: @GuilhermeOderdenge I have made an update. Let me know if you aren't using ES6.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming "page.jsx" contains methods "enableButton" and "disableButton".

while updating the state do you have any other state properties apart from "canSubmit"? if you have other state properties along with "canSubmit" you are forcing them to become undefined by doing

```
  this.setState({
    canSubmit: true
  );
```

So i am assuming there is a state property called "xyz" existed along with "canSubmit" state property. so update the state like below

```
this.setState({
    canSubmit: true,
    xyz:this.state.xyz
  );
```

or better you try to use react update addon to update state. more find here https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/update.html

**Update**

Try the below code in your page.jsx file

```
  shouldComponentUpdate(object nextProps, object nextState){
     if(this.state.canSubmit==nextState.canSubmit){
        return false
     }
  }
```

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_currentElement' of null` — and no, I have only `canSubmit` so far.

Comment: ok. try to in include "shouldComponentUpdate" method in your page.jsx